# How do I clean up CVS vendor branch imports?

Tags: cvs, cvs2svn

I have a CVS repository with a directory containing two vendor branches.  The initial code was obtained from one source and checked in with a vendor name say X.  Several years later, new code was checked in with another vendor branch name Y.

If I view the rcs file (FILE,v) in a text editor, I see X:1.1.1, a few tags... and then Y:1.1.1

This hasn't caused any issues that I'm aware of in using CVS, but now I want to migrate to Subversion using cvs2svn.

I get errors from cvs2svn like the following:

> WARNING: in '/home/cvs/src/contrib/one-true-awk/FILES,v':    branch
>   '1.1.1' already has name 'Y',    cannot also have name 'X', ignoring
>   the latter

Ideally, I'd like to use the newer vendor tag Y for the entire history, but I'd also be willing to make it go away and use the older tag. Either way, I need to clean this up so that cvs2svn can convert the repository to Subversion.

Are there any commands I can run on the files from CVS to repair this mess or manual steps in the ,v file I can do? I've tried removing the newer Y branch line, but that alone doesn't work due to the crazy numbering in the commits.  A 1.2 revision was created due to the second import and it's causing cvs2svn to fail as well.

Comment: Tricky business indeed. Found out both things the hard way too: ① vendor branch numbers must be odd, not even, and ② you use different vendor branches for every source (e.g. 1.1.1 for $parent_bsd, 1.1.3 for $parent_of_parent_bsd, 1.1.101 for FSF, 1.1.103 for XF86, 1.1.109 for lynx, etc.) ⇒ had to make a project-global registry of vendors (branch tag and number) eventually…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up asking on the cvs2svn users mailing list.  I received the following response from Michael Haggerty:

> I don't believe that this error can come from importing twice.  AFAIK
>   each time you import you would create a new vendor branch; e.g. 1.1.1,
>   1.1.3, etc. (the last number is always odd for vendor branches), and each vendor branch would get its own symbolic name.  The situation you
>   are experiencing is that you have only one vendor branch, 1.1.1, and
>   it somehow has two symbolic names, 'X' and 'Y'.
>
> If you tell cvs2svn just to ignore the unwanted symbol name, then the
>   conversion should go through without complaints.  To do this, you need
>   to start cvs2svn via the options-file method and then use a
>   IgnoreSymbolTransform.  See cvs2svn-example.options for documentation.
>
> If you want to be super-careful, you might first want to verify that
>   the symbol name that you are ignoring is really redundant in every
>   file. Or, I think it would also work to transform the unwanted symbol
>   name into the wanted symbol name, because cvs2svn ignores symbols that
>   appear twice with the *same* value.  This would require something like
>
> RegexpSymbolTransform(r'X', r'Y')

I then used the IgnoreSymbolTransform to hide the extra symbols.

Additionally, I ran into a secondary error due to files that had been patched in HEAD and then a newer import occurred.  By force committing the files, I was able to get them back onto HEAD and avoid this:

**ERROR: File '/home/cvs/src/contrib/one-true-awk/FIXES,v' has default branch=1.1.1 but also a revision 1.2**